# Cannot get Chrome version 42 to accept localhost cerfificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, oauth-2.0, localhost

Attempting to develop OAuth 2 web app in Visual Studio 2013. My development website needs ssl to accomplish this.

So... how do I get Chrome to accept my localhost's ssl certificate? There are various solutions for this out there, none of which work with Chrome's current version (42).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In short: use `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` . 
For a more detailed answer see https://superuser.com/a/903159/291741.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the flag doesn't work.That may be because the ssl url is https://localhost:44300/. Visual Studio doesn't seem to offer a choice in that.